# How to get number of posts to appear in extended information section?

Tags: seo, google, forum, microdata

I have forums website, and I am looking through Google search engine, and I can see that some (not mine) forums have something like this under the link of the site:

> 28 nov 2005 - Number of posts: 4 - ‎Number of authors: 3

(This may not be exactly what this text since I translated it from my native language)

How do I get this information to appear? What do I need to add to my forum in order for Google to catch it?

I am aware of microdata, I just don't know which one (and how) should I use here.

Comment: Presumably you're referencing [Rich Snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en)?

Comment: @dan: yes, rich snippets it is, but I don't know which one (and how) to use them in order to make this datta appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does this automatically; it's not based on any particular "micro data" or tags in the html code. As far as I know, Google just looks at the content on your forum. This makes for a very impressive trick!

[image: Google search results for forum content]

This feature was described on the [Google blog several years ago](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/surfacing-forum-posts-in-search-results.html):

> Today, we introduced a new search feature that makes it easier for you
>   to find forum posts or discussions related to what you’re searching
>   for. This new addition to Google search results applies to sites that
>   tend to have a large number of posts on a specific topic. When several
>   different discussions on a site are relevant to your query, we indent
>   them under the primary result and include the date of each post.

The biggest problem is that often times the post/author count is out of date, even after the thread has been archived for a while.  Google doesn't disclose how it crawls the data so it's possible that adding in some microdata could improve the accuracy of the results.

We theorized that adding a thread's page number to the html title on each page in a given thread would help Google but results were inconclusive. Read more on this experiment: http://www.ninjapost.com/blog/improving-seo-for-forum-search-results/)